# sed regexp, number reformatting: how to escape for bash

Tags: regex, sed, replace, regex-group

I have a working (in macOS app Patterns) RegExp that reformats GeoJSON MultiPolygon coordinates, but don't know how to escape it for `sed`.

The file I'm working on is over 90 Mb in size, so bash terminal looks like the ideal place and `sed` the perfect tool for the job.

Search Text Example:

```
[[[379017.735,6940036.7955],[379009.8431,6940042.5761],[379000.4869,6940048.9545],[378991.5455,6940057.8128],[378984.0665,6940066.0744],[378974.7072,6940076.2152],[378962.8639,6940090.5283],[378954.5822,6940101.4028],[378947.9369,6940111.3128],[378941.4564,6940119.5094],[378936.2565,6940128.1229],[378927.6089,6940141.4764],[378919.6611,6940154.0312],[378917.21,6940158.7053],[378913.7614,6940163.4443],[378913.6515,6940163.5893],[378911.4453,6940166.3531],
```

Desired outcome:

```
[[[37.9017735,69.400367955],[37.90098431,69.400425761],[37.90004869,69.400489545],[37.89915455,69.400578128],[37.89840665,69.400660744],[37.89747072,69.400762152],[37.89628639,69.400905283],[37.89545822,69.401014028],[37.89479369,69.401113128],[37.89414564,69.401195094],[37.89362565,69.401281229],[37.89276089,69.401414764],[37.89196611,69.401540312],[37.891721,69.401587053],[37.89137614,69.401634443],[37.89136515,69.401635893],[37.89114453,69.401663531],
```

My current RegExp:

```
((?:\[)[0-9]{2})([0-9]+)(\.)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]{2})([0-9]+)(\.)([0-9]+(?:\]))
```

and reformatting:

```
$1\.$2$4,$6.$7$9
```

The command should be something along these lines:

```
sed -i -e 's/ The RegExp escaped /$1\.$2$4,$6.$7$9/g' large_file.geojson
```

But what should be escaped in the RegExp to make it work?
My attempts always complain of being unbalanced.

I'm sorry if this has already been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find even after extensive searching.

---

**Edit: 2017-01-07**: I didn't make it clear that the file contains properties other than just the GPS-points. One of the other example values picked from GeoJSON Feature properties is `"35.642.1.001_001"`, which should be left unchanged. The braces check in my original regex is there for this reason.

Comment: Do you have to worry about checking the brackets? Try `sed -i -E 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]*)\.([0-9]+)/\1.\2\3/g' large_file.geojson` (see [demo](http://ideone.com/9tZRS0) working [like this](https://regex101.com/r/DGyYJq/1)).

Comment: Are all values guaranteed to be >= 1000?

Comment: That one escaped, didn't know just hitting enter submits, sorry.

There are other values that contain numbers in different formats, I didn't go through all the items in the massive text file, so there might be some values that might not be over 1000. Checking for braces felt like an adequate failsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regex is not legal in `sed`; since it uses Perl syntax, my recommendation would be to use `perl` instead. The regular expression works exactly as-is, and even the command line is almost the same; you just need to add the `-p` option to get `perl` to operate in filter mode (which `sed` does by default). I would also recommend adding an argument suffix to the `-i` option (whether using `sed` or `perl`), so that you have a backup of the original file in case something goes horribly wrong. As for quoting, all you need to do is put the substitution command in single quotation marks:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e \
's/((?:\[)[0-9]{2})([0-9]+)(\.)([0-9]+)(,)([0-9]{2})([0-9]+)(\.)([0-9]+(?:\]))/$1\.$2$4,$6.$7$9/g' \
large_file.geojson
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer, with a simple example how to use perl in this case. This one solved my problem and took in account the braces that were there as an failsafe as the rest of the data might contain other similarly formatted values. The note about `-i` was a great extra help, as there is always the chance things do go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is just like you showed, you needn't worry about the brackets. You may use a POSIX ERE enabled with `-E` (or `-r` in some other distributions) like this:

```
sed -i -E 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]*)\.([0-9]+)/\1.\2\3/g' large_file.geojson
```

Or a POSIX BRE:

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]\+\)/\1.\2\3/g' large_file.geojson
```

See an [online demo](http://ideone.com/9tZRS0).

You may see [how this regex works here](https://regex101.com/r/DGyYJq/1) (just a demo, not proof).

Note that in POSIX BRE you need to escape `{` and `}` in limiting / range quantifiers and `(` and `)` in grouping constructs, and the `+` quantifier, else they denote literal symbols. In POSIX ERE, you do not need to escape the special chars to make them special, this POSIX flavor is closer to the modern regexes.

Also, you need to use `\n` notation inside the replacement pattern, not `$n`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple sed will do it:

```
$ echo "$var"
[[[379017.735,6940036.7955],[379009.8431,6940042.5761],[379000.4869,6940048.9545],[378991.5455,6940057.8128],[378984.0665,6940066.0744],[378974.7072,6940076.2152],[378962.8639,6940090.5283],[378954.5822,6940101.4028],[378947.9369,6940111.3128],[378941.4564,6940119.5094],[378936.2565,6940128.1229],[378927.6089,6940141.4764],[378919.6611,6940154.0312],[378917.21,6940158.7053],[378913.7614,6940163.4443],[378913.6515,6940163.5893],[378911.4453,6940166.3531],

$ echo "$var" | sed  's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\./.\1/g'
[[[379.017735,6940.0367955],[379.0098431,6940.0425761],[379.0004869,6940.0489545],[378.9915455,6940.0578128],[378.9840665,6940.0660744],[378.9747072,6940.0762152],[378.9628639,6940.0905283],[378.9545822,6940.1014028],[378.9479369,6940.1113128],[378.9414564,6940.1195094],[378.9362565,6940.1281229],[378.9276089,6940.1414764],[378.9196611,6940.1540312],[378.91721,6940.1587053],[378.9137614,6940.1634443],[378.9136515,6940.1635893],[378.9114453,6940.1663531],
```

Comment: This is not what he asked for.

Comment: I'd have sworn he wanted the decimal moved three places.  Anyway, just change the `\{3\}` to `\{4\}`, and it shifts the decimal four places.

Comment: That still doesn't work because the decimal points are not in the same position.

Comment: I do not understand.  It get's EXACTLY what he has in his example.

Comment: input: [379017.735,6940036.7955]
your output(with \{4\}): [37.9017735,694.00367955]
your output(with \{3\}): [379.017735,6940.0367955]
**desired output:** [37.9017735,69.400367955]

The desired output must be 2 digits then a period. Not 3 and 4 or 4 and 5 digits then a period.

Comment: Oh -- so ALWAYS two digits then a decimal, not all the output scaled by a constant power of 10!  Or perhaps he want the first always shifted four and the second always shifted five?

Comment: Originally I was looking for a way to modify values from old Finnish KKJ/YK coordinate system for Leaflet.js use (I know it doesn't work like that). I left those details out to keep the question more general and on topic of `sed` escaping, which could benefit other users and solve my problem why it didn't like my expression syntax at the same time. The goal was to group values to `([0-9]{2}).([0-9]+)` as in my desired outcome example.